# How to pass both arrays and single cells as arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a custom function that will take both regular numbers and arrays as arguments. Bellow is my VBA code:

```
Function PVV(i, n, CF)
    FV = NPV(i, CF)
    PVV = PV(i, n - 1, 0, FV)
End Function
```

CF is an array, i and n are single cells with numbers. When I try to call this function, I get an error that says: "Compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined expected".

Any advice?

Comment: When you say CF is an *array*, do you mean a *VBA array* or a range of cells in a worksheet row or column ??

Comment: [`NPV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/npv-function) *requires* the `values` argument to be an array of `Double`, and at least one must be positive and one must be negative. As far as advice goes, I'd declare your variable types and read the documentation on the functions you're calling.  The documentation of `PV` [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/pv-function). If you want to change how the built in functions behave, you'll basically need to re-implement them.